# Sql query page refresh

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Experts,

As-Is

I am having application in which textview is displaying the database table count.Which keep change upon inserting the data in to the database table
And issue is changed data is appearing whenever i closed and reopen again only.

To-Be

Textview should show the count the moment data is inserted in to the table. Like auto refresh something like that. Could you assist.
my code is

```
String strData1 = "";
Cursor c =  dbhndlr.getAllEntries();
if (c!= null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            strData1 += c.getString(0);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}

tex.setText(strData1);

String strData2 = "";
Cursor c1 =  dbhndlr.getAllEntries1();
if (c1!= null) {
    if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            strData2 += c1.getString(0);
        } while (c1.moveToNext());
    }
}

tex1.setText(strData2);
```

DB

```
public Cursor getAllEntries(){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  count (*) FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return  cur;
}

public Cursor getAllEntries1(){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  count (*) FROM " + TABLE_LABELS2;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cur1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return  cur1;
}

public List<String> getAllLabels1(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  count (*) FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    final ArrayList<String> row1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor1.getString(1));
        } while (cursor1.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor1.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

Comment: As long as you are using SQLite DB you must query from the and set the value to `TextView` yourself everywhere you are showing the count. But if you switch to [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database/)  you can get a callback each time some data has changed in the database.

Comment: Hello Abbas. Thanks Indeed agreed your point.Could you share the revise coding for realm with above requirements.

Comment: There is little to no point in posting the complete code. You should familiarize yourself with RealmDB and once you have done that you should implement it. Then if you find you're stuck then you should post a new question for that particular problem.